# Pygame: drawing a checkered board, continues to draw at the end of the box

Tags: python, pygame

I drew an 8x8 checkered board in the middle of the screen, there is suppose to be empty space around the board but at the end of each row and column it looks like it continues to draw to the edge of the screen.  Is there anything to fix this or will I have to create another surface around the board?

Note: I think the problem is somewhere in the drawMainBoard function. I tried creating a line where each box starts and ends and the line stops where it should but the board continues to draw to the edge of the screen.

```
import pygame._view
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import*
import time
import random

FPS=30
fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()

displayWidth=600
displayHeight=600

Xmargin=(displayWidth/12)*2
Ymargin=(displayHeight/12)*2

boardRows=8
boardColumns=8

boxx=(displayWidth-(Xmargin*2))/8
boxy=(displayHeight-(Ymargin*2))/8



DISPLAYSURF=pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth,displayHeight),0,32)

colorRed=   (255,0,0)
colorBlack= (0,0,0)
colorWhite= (255,255,255)
colorRed2=  (150,0,0)
colorBlack2=(10,10,10)

pygame.init()

myFont=pygame.font.SysFont("ariel",15)

def mainscreen():
    DISPLAYSURF.fill((255,255,255))

    drawMainboard()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()

    fpsClock.tick(FPS)

def drawBox(boxstart,boxend,boxcolor):
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF,boxcolor,(boxstart,boxend),0)






def drawMainboard():
    firstColor=colorBlack
    boxxstart=Xmargin
    boxystart=Ymargin
    boxxend=Xmargin+boxx
    boxyend=Ymargin+boxy
    lettercount=0

    boxstart=(boxxstart,boxystart)
    boxend=(boxxend,boxyend)
    for columns in range(0,boardColumns):
        if firstColor==colorRed:
            firstColor=colorBlack
        else:
            firstColor=colorRed
        for rows in range(0,boardRows):
            drawBox(boxstart,boxend,firstColor)
            label=myFont.render(str(lettercount),20,(0,0,255))
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(label,(boxxstart,boxystart))
            pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF,colorWhite,(boxxend,boxyend),(boxxstart,boxystart),1)
            lettercount+=1
            if firstColor==colorRed:
                firstColor=colorBlack
            else:
                firstColor=colorRed

            boxxstart+=boxx
            boxxend+=boxx
            boxstart=(boxxstart,boxystart)
            boxend=((boxxend),(boxyend))
        boxxstart=Xmargin
        boxxend=Xmargin+boxx
        boxystart+=boxy
        boxyend+=boxy
        boxstart=(boxxstart,boxystart)
        boxend=(boxxend,boxyend)


while True:
    mainscreen()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is within your `drawBox` function. You pass in the parameters `boxstart` and `boxend`, which represents the top left and the bottom right point of the rect to draw.

But the `pygame.draw.rect` function expects a `Rect` like object or tuple, representing the x and y coordinate of the top left point of the rect and it's *size*. So when you pass in the values `(450, 100), (500, 150)`, you don't draw a `Rect` from `(450, 100)` to `(500, 150)`, but a rect starting at `(450, 100)` with a length of 500 and a height of 150.

An easy fix is to calculate the correct size in the function:

```
def drawBox(boxstart,boxend,boxcolor):
    sx, sy = boxstart
    ex, ey = boxend
    r = Rect(sx, sy, ex-sx, ey-sy)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF,boxcolor,r,0)
```

or simply use the `Rect` class instead:

```
from itertools import cycle

...

def drawMainboard():
    # the current rect we're going to draw
    current = Rect((Xmargin, Ymargin), (boxx, boxy))

    # the colors we use
    colors = cycle((pygame.color.Color('Black'), pygame.color.Color('Red')))

    lettercount = 0
    for _ in range(0, boardRows):
        # switch colors on each row, so the last rect on a row
        # has the same color as the starting rect on the next row
        # only need on an even number of columns
        next(colors)
        for _ in range(0, boardColumns):
            # switch color and draw rect
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, next(colors), current, 0)
            # draw label. We can simply use 'current' as position
            label=myFont.render(str(lettercount),20,(0,0,255))
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(label, current)
            # draw the line. We can simply use current.topleft, current.bottomright
            pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF,colorWhite, current.topleft, current.bottomright, 1)
            lettercount += 1
            # move the current rect to the next column
            current.move_ip((boxx, 0))
        # for the next row, start at 'Xmargin' and move the rect down one row
        current.topleft = Xmargin, current.top + boxy
```

Comment: I added an easier `drawMainboard` function.

Comment: I haven't learned all of the functions of all the different modules yet. Pretty much learning them only when I use them so you are really helping me out, much appreciated and thanks :)